# How to scan two-sided (Duplex?) using WIA - C#

Tags: c#, scanning, wia

I'm writing a C # method that scans a lot of documents, but I need to scan these documents two-sided, ie for each sheet, scan the front and back of the document using the scanner's ADF. But I've tried all the ways I found on the internet and I could not. My code is below:

```
        //user select the scanner
        int indexScanner = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Connect to the first available scanner
        var device = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[indexScanner - 1].Connect();

        // Select the scanner
        var scannerItem = device.Items[1];

        int resolution = 150;
        int width_pixel = 1250;
        int height_pixel = 1700;
        int color_mode = 1;
        int adf_mode = 1;
        int pages_mode = 1;

        device.Properties["3096"].set_Value(pages_mode);
        //device.Properties["3088"].set_Value(adf_mode);
        scannerItem.Properties["3088"].set_Value(adf_mode);

        AdjustScannerSettings(scannerItem, resolution, 0, 0, width_pixel, height_pixel, 0, 0, color_mode);

        CommonDialogClass dlg = new CommonDialogClass();

            object scanResult = dlg.ShowTransfer(scannerItem, FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, true);

            if (scanResult != null)
            {
                ImageFile image = (ImageFile)scanResult;

                string filename = "scan.jpeg";

                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                image.SaveFile(filename);
            }

            scanResult = dlg.ShowTransfer(scannerItem, FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, true);

            if (scanResult != null)
            {
                ImageFile image = (ImageFile)scanResult;

                string filename = "scan1.jpeg";

                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                image.SaveFile(filename);
            }
```

Comment: Could not what - what specifically does not work? Configuring the scanner to do both sides, retrieving both sides of the scan from the scanner, something else?

Comment: The scanner is always being made from the flatbed, and when I can use the ADF, it does not scan the back of the sheet.